# TensorFlow sound recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am making my own version of the example for [TensorFlow audio recognition](https://data-flair.training/blogs/tensorflow-audio-recognition/) to recognise some sound effects instead of speech.
I am getting the following error during training of my model for sound recognition:

> 2019-09-11 19:16:38.221677: E
>   tensorflow/core/kernels/mfcc_mel_filterbank.cc:153] Missing 5 bands 
>   starting at 0 in mel-frequency design. Perhaps too many channels or
>   not enough frequency resolution in spectrum. (input_length: 257
>   input_sample_rate: 44100 output_channel_count: 40
>   lower_frequency_limit: 20 upper_frequency_limit: 4000

Can you please explain what this means, and how I can fix the problem? My audio clips are all around 1 second long, 44.1khz and are in stereo.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the example expects a sample rate of audio files of 16000khz however I was supplying 44100khz files.

I fixed the problem by adding the following flag:

```
--sample_rate=44100
```